# How to get an array with unique values using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array with duplicated items. How can I get an array with unique items?

```
a= [{id: "1", campus: "c1"}, {id: "1", campus: "c1"}, {id: "2", campus: "c2"}, {id: "2", campus: "c2"}]
```

I want result with unique objects

```
a= [{id: "1", campus: "c1"}, {id: "2", campus: "c2"}]
```

Comment: Hint: You can use `filter`.

Comment: Hint: You can use underscore js

Comment: You do not need AngularJS to solve this. Like Tushar said `filter` would help you. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Comment: Are you looking for a underscore/lodash solution?

Comment: @Tushar Please suggest best way with respect to performance..Thanks

Comment: @VeeraBhadraRao I've added answer below, as you're okay with lodash and underscore, please add those tags in the question.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as follow:

```js
var arr = [{
    id: "1",
    campus: "c1"
}, {
    id: "1",
    campus: "c1"
}, {
    id: "2",
    campus: "c2"
}, {
    id: "2",
    campus: "c2"
}];

// Keep an array of elements whose id is added in filtered array
var elementId = [];

var newArr = arr.filter(el => {
    if (elementId.indexOf(el.id) === -1) {
        // If not present in array, then add it
        elementId.push(el.id);
        return true;
    } else {
        // Already present in array, don't add it
        return false;
    }
});

console.log(newArr);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(newArr, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

---

Based on OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990611/how-to-get-an-array-with-unique-values-using-angularjs#comment57710416_34990611)

> Please suggest best way with respect to performance..

**If you're okay with underscore/lodash**

You can use [`_.uniqWith`](https://lodash.com/docs#uniqWith)

```
_.uniqWith(arr, _.isEqual);
```

```js
var arr = [{
    id: "1",
    campus: "c1"
}, {
    id: "1",
    campus: "c1"
}, {
    id: "2",
    campus: "c2"
}, {
    id: "2",
    campus: "c2"
}];

var newArr = _.uniqWith(arr, _.isEqual);
console.log(newArr);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(newArr, 0, 4);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.0.1/lodash.js"></script>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

You can also use [`_.uniqBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#uniqBy)

```
_.uniqBy(arr, 'id');
```

```js
var arr = [{
    id: "1",
    campus: "c1"
}, {
    id: "1",
    campus: "c1"
}, {
    id: "2",
    campus: "c2"
}, {
    id: "2",
    campus: "c2"
}];

var newArr = _.uniqBy(arr, 'id');
console.log(newArr);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(newArr, 0, 4);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.0.1/lodash.js"></script>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular jqLite implementation does not contain the $.filter function.

You have to provide your own implementation. You can do something like:

```
function getUniqueArray(array){
  var result = [];
  for(var x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
  if(result.indexOf(array[x]) == -1)
        result.push(array[x]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: what is `t`? in t.indexOf(array[x]) == -1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unique` from [AngularUI](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#unique)

```
<li ng-repeat="x in myArr | unique:id">
  {{ x.campus }}
</li>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uxo0jue3/6/)